# max_user_connections error with mysql

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I am using below data source configuration setting but after some time , I am getting  "**User 'username' has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 10)**" . maxIdle connection is set to 1 but still We are gettign this error . Can someone please advice what could be root cause ?

**Note** ==> we do not have option to increase the max connection limit which is currently set to 10 .

**Update ==>** my java program which is using Spring JdbcTemplate , able to run first few my sql statement but after some time it is giving error . Also if I set "maxIdle" property value to 0 , then it is working without issue .

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://mysqlServerName:3306/mydb"/>
    <property name="username" value="username"/>
    <property name="password" value="password"/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
    <property name="maxIdle"  value="1" />
</bean>
```

Comment: You may want to play with the `maxActive` value .

Comment: tried with below but sill getting same error -                                                                                                                                                                                 <property name="maxIdle"  value="1" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="1" />

Comment: How are you using this? You aren't recreating the application context just because you need a `JdbcTemplate`? The `BasicDataSource` has a default max limit of 8, so you must be recreating something ...

Comment: thanks Deinum . my bad ..  I was creating application context multiple time  .  I have change the code to initialize the context only once and it is working fine now . thanks much for your suggestion ..

Comment: Why are you even creating it manually? One of the Spring initializing methods should do that, and you should be using Dependency injection instead.

Comment: my program is console based so context need to be created manually .  I was keeping the context in static field . the problem was due to multiple call of method which cause multiple times context creation as you pointed out . for data source and other bean I am using spring dependency injection ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by **[Denium](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum)**

How are you using this? You aren't recreating the application context just because you need a JdbcTemplate? The BasicDataSource has a default max limit of 8, so you must be recreating something ... – M. Deinum 3 hours ago

thanks Deinum . my bad .. I was creating application context multiple time . I have change the code to initialize the context only once and it is working fine now . thanks much for your suggestion .. – Raj 3 hours ago

Why are you even creating it manually? One of the Spring initializing methods should do that, and you should be using Dependency injection instead. – M. Deinum 3 hours ago

my program is console based so context need to be created manually . I was keeping the context in static field . the problem was due to multiple call of method which cause multiple times context creation as you pointed out . for data source and other bean I am using spring dependency injection .. – Raj 3 hours ago